# precedence not working properly in css3

Tags: css

In the below code i have `h1` tag when i put this on `<aside>` or `<article>` tag ,value defined in `article` selector always override `aside` in both case when we set `<article>` tag as child or parent.

```css
aside h4
{
 font-style:italic!important;
 color:yellow;
}
article h4
{
 color:black;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

```html
<article> 
  <aside>
    <h4>HEADING</h4>
  </aside>
</article>

<aside>
  <article>  
    <h4>HEADING</h4>
  </article>
</aside>
```

Comment: Remove the !important from your font-style declaration and compare the results to the color declaration. Then think about why removing the !important so affects the output. Then think about why the color declaration is acting the way it is without the !important.

Comment: @BoltClock my question is why **`<h1>HEADING<h1>`** always follows value provided in **`article h4 {}`**  even we put **`<aside>`** in **`<article>`** or **`<article>`** in **`<aside>`**

Comment: I think `.article h4` has higher specificity from `.aside h4` when `<article>` is inside `<aside>`. That's why it's overriding the color specified in `aside` selector which is the parent in the later HTML.

Comment: in both situation `.article h4` override `aside h4` even we set `aside` as parent or `article` as parent check in above example @HamzaIshak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the `h4` is always black is because the last rule in CSS override previous rules.

Why the last rule won't make its `font-style` normal is because the previous rule has `!important`, and as such override any later defined rules, unless of course they as well have `!important`.

Whether you now toggle the `h4` parents won't make any difference since a rule with a space between the selectors, like in `aside h4`, will affect any child element, no matter how deep nested the target element is.

```css
article h4
{
 color:black;
    font-style:normal;
}
aside h4
{
 font-style:italic;
 color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<article> 
  <aside>
    <h4>HEADING</h4>
  </aside>
</article>

<aside>
  <article>  
    <h4>HEADING</h4>
  </article>
</aside>
```

Comment: ohh so that's was the reason got it now.

Answer (score 0):

```css
aside > h4
{
    font-style:italic!important;
    color:yellow;
}
article > h4
{
     color:black;
     font-style:normal!important;
}
```

```html
<article> 
    <aside>
         <h4>HEADING</h4>
    </aside>
</article>

<aside>
    <article>  
         <h4>HEADING</h4>
    </article>
</aside>
```

Comment: yes I know this one work well but I want to know what precedence follows  in case of when we select element by `aside h4` ? in css tag also have different-different  precedence?

Comment: you wrote aside inside article and article inside aside thats why browser doesnt support.Thats why i am giving the precedence So that browser automatically added style.aside>h4 indicates i am adding style in which h4 is just after aside.

Comment: May be I explain my self wrong but my question was different but thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
If we can write code in this way then no need to use precedence.

 <article> 
     <h4>HEADING</h4>
 </article>
 <aside>
     <h4>HEADING</h4>
 </aside>

aside h4
{
     font-style:italic!important;
     color:yellow;
 }
 article h4
 {
     color:black;
     font-style:normal!important;
 }
```